# Plotly 3D scatterplots only use a limited set of symbols/shapes in R

Tags: r, macos, plotly

I am trying to generate a 3D version (plotly) of a 2D PCA plot (ggplot). However, when trying to assign shapes/symbols to a variable, I simply get circles most of the time.

I used a blob of code I've found online to plot all available shapes:

```
library(plotly)

vals <- schema(F)$traces$scatter$attributes$marker$symbol$values
vals <- grep("[a-z]", vals, value = TRUE)

grid_size <- ceiling(sqrt(length(vals)))

plot_ly() %>%
  add_markers(
    x = rep(seq_len(grid_size), each = grid_size, length.out = length(vals)),
    y = rep(seq_len(grid_size), times = grid_size, length.out = length(vals)),
    text = vals,
    hoverinfo = "text",
    marker = list(
      symbol = vals,
      size = 30,
      line = list(
        color = "black",
        width = 2
      )
    )
  )
```

This generated the expected range of figures (in 2D)

[image]

However, when trying to use certain shapes in 3D, only a few shapes seem to be available and I get filled circles most of the time:

```
fig <- plot_ly(pcaData, x = ~PC1, y = ~PC2, z = ~PC3, 
               text = ~sample,
               width = 800, height = 600
               ) %>%
  add_markers(
    symbol = ~sample,
    symbols = vals[1:24]
  ) %>%
  add_text(textfont = list(
                          family = "sans serif",
                          size = 10,
                          color = toRGB("black")), 
           textposition = "top right",
           showlegend=F)


fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    title = "All samples",
    autosize = F,
    scene = list(bgcolor = "#f0f0f0")
)

fig
```

[image]

Only the basic (full) and open (empty) version of the first 3 shapes (circle, square, diamond). The next 2 in list (cross, x) only show the basic (full) version of the shape. Any other shape is replaced by the default. I wanted to use 'triangle-up' to imitate a 2D plot done with ggplot2.

I couldn't find online anything about this. Every thread I find seems to be under the assumption of all plotly shapes being able to be used in 3D scatterplots. Should they? Or only a few shapes are available in 3D? Is there something wrong with my installation?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6.7

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plotly_4.10.2               vsn_3.62.0                  kableExtra_1.3.4           
 [4] knitr_1.44                  ggVennDiagram_1.2.3         patchwork_1.1.3            
 [7] RColorBrewer_1.1-3          pheatmap_1.0.12             rtracklayer_1.54.0         
[10] ggnewscale_0.4.9            ggbeeswarm_0.7.2            ggsignif_0.6.4             
[13] ggrepel_0.9.3               tibble_3.2.1                gridExtra_2.3              
[16] ggplot2_3.4.3               tidyr_1.3.0                 plyr_1.8.8                 
[19] dplyr_1.1.3                 tximport_1.22.0             DESeq2_1.34.0              
[22] SummarizedExperiment_1.24.0 Biobase_2.54.0              MatrixGenerics_1.6.0       
[25] matrixStats_1.0.0           GenomicRanges_1.46.1        GenomeInfoDb_1.30.1        
[28] IRanges_2.28.0              S4Vectors_0.32.4            BiocGenerics_0.40.0        
[31] sva_3.42.0                  BiocParallel_1.28.3         genefilter_1.76.0          
[34] mgcv_1.9-0                  nlme_3.1-163               

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] fastmatch_1.1-4          BiocFileCache_2.2.1      systemfonts_1.0.4       
  [4] lazyeval_0.2.2           splines_4.1.2            crosstalk_1.2.0         
  [7] pathview_1.34.0          digest_0.6.33            htmltools_0.5.6         
 [10] fansi_1.0.4              magrittr_2.0.3           memoise_2.0.1           
 [13] tzdb_0.4.0               limma_3.50.3             Biostrings_2.62.0       
 [16] readr_2.1.4              annotate_1.72.0          svglite_2.1.1           
 [19] prettyunits_1.2.0        RVenn_1.1.0              colorspace_2.1-0        
 [22] blob_1.2.4               rvest_1.0.3              rappdirs_0.3.3          
 [25] xfun_0.40                jsonlite_1.8.7           crayon_1.5.2            
 [28] RCurl_1.98-1.12          graph_1.72.0             survival_3.5-7          
 [31] glue_1.6.2               gtable_0.3.4             zlibbioc_1.40.0         
 [34] XVector_0.34.0           webshot_0.5.5            DelayedArray_0.20.0     
 [37] Rgraphviz_2.38.0         scales_1.2.1             DBI_1.1.3               
 [40] edgeR_3.36.0             Rcpp_1.0.11              viridisLite_0.4.2       
 [43] xtable_1.8-4             progress_1.2.2           bit_4.0.5               
 [46] preprocessCore_1.56.0    htmlwidgets_1.6.2        httr_1.4.7              
 [49] fgsea_1.20.0             ellipsis_0.3.2           farver_2.1.1            
 [52] pkgconfig_2.0.3          XML_3.99-0.14            dbplyr_2.3.4            
 [55] locfit_1.5-9.8           utf8_1.2.3               dynamicTreeCut_1.63-1   
 [58] labeling_0.4.3           tidyselect_1.2.0         rlang_1.1.1             
 [61] reshape2_1.4.4           later_1.3.1              AnnotationDbi_1.56.2    
 [64] munsell_0.5.0            tools_4.1.2              cachem_1.0.8            
 [67] cli_3.6.1                generics_0.1.3           RSQLite_2.3.1           
 [70] evaluate_0.22            stringr_1.5.0            fastmap_1.1.1           
 [73] yaml_2.3.7               org.Hs.eg.db_3.14.0      bit64_4.0.5             
 [76] purrr_1.0.2              KEGGREST_1.34.0          reactable_0.4.4         
 [79] mime_0.12                KEGGgraph_1.54.0         xml2_1.3.5              
 [82] biomaRt_2.50.3           compiler_4.1.2           rstudioapi_0.15.0       
 [85] beeswarm_0.4.0           filelock_1.0.2           curl_5.0.2              
 [88] png_0.1-8                affyio_1.64.0            geneplotter_1.72.0      
 [91] stringi_1.7.12           lattice_0.21-8           Matrix_1.6-1.1          
 [94] vctrs_0.6.3              pillar_1.9.0             lifecycle_1.0.3         
 [97] BiocManager_1.30.22      eulerr_7.0.0             data.table_1.14.8       
[100] bitops_1.0-7             httpuv_1.6.11            affy_1.72.0             
[103] R6_2.5.1                 BiocIO_1.4.0             promises_1.2.1          
[106] vipor_0.4.5              rjson_0.2.21             withr_2.5.1             
[109] GenomicAlignments_1.30.0 Rsamtools_2.10.0         GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.7  
[112] parallel_4.1.2           hms_1.1.3                grid_4.1.2              
[115] rmarkdown_2.25           shiny_1.7.5              restfulr_0.0.15
```

Comment: For 3d scatters only a very limited set of shapes is available: `One of ( "circle" | "circle-open" | "cross" | "diamond" | "diamond-open" | "square" | "square-open" | "x" )`. See https://plotly.com/r/reference/scatter3d/#scatter3d-marker-symbol

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm dumb. For some reason I always ended up in the 2D-side of the manual when searching for symbol information.